# Cplex get coefficients of objective function

Tags: java, cplex

I have an `IloCplex` object and I want to get the coefficients of the `IloObjective` with the Cplex Java api.

With this code I get the `IloObjective` and `IloNumExpr` but I can't access the coefficients.

```
IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
cplex.importModel("model.lp");
IloObjective obj = cplex.getObjective();
IloNumExpr expr = obj.getExpr();
```

How can I get the coefficients of `IloObjective` or `IloNumExpr`?

Comment: You can probably cast this `expr` to [`IloLinearNumExpr`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloLinearNumExpr.html) and then use the [`linearIterator`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloLinearNumExpr.html#linearIterator()) method to retrieve the coefficients.

Comment: Your answer works for me, please write it as a response and not as commentary so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `model.lp` file contains a linear model, `expr` should be an instance of [`IloLinearNumExpr`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloLinearNumExpr.html), and you should be able to iterate over it using the [`linearIterator`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloLinearNumExpr.html#linearIterator()) method:

```
if (expr instanceof IloLinearNumExpr) {
    IloLinearNumExpr lexpr = (IloLinearNumExpr) expr;

    IloLinearNumExprIterator it = lexpr.linearIterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        IloNumVar var = it.nextNumVar();
        double coeff = it.getValue();
        System.out.println(var + " " + coeff);
    }
}
```